# Excluding password fields from Django / Mezzanine's user account form?

Tags: django, authentication, mezzanine

I'm using [Mozilla Persona](http://persona.org/) and [django-browserid](http://django-browserid.readthedocs.org/en/) for authentication in a [Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/) site and don't need Mezzanine's password fields.

I've tried Mezzanine's [restricting account fields](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/user-accounts.html#restricting-account-fields) settings but it doesn't work and the profile fields still show:

```
ACCOUNTS_PROFILE_FORM_EXCLUDE_FIELDS = (
    "email",
    "password1",
    "password2",
)
```

Is there a way to exclude or disable the Django & Mezzanine password fields, maybe automatically setting an unusable password for users that log in with Persona? I'm looking at the source code in Mezzanine's Accounts app, specifically [ProfileForm](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/accounts/forms.py#L64), but am not sure what is the best way to proceed.

**UPDATE**

For now I've hard-coded the form fields in the template, omitting password fields, eg:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>{{ title }}</legend>
  <form method="post"{% if form.is_multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %}>
    {# {% fields_for form %} #}

    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="referrer" value="//{{request.META.HTTP_HOST}}/users/{{request.user}}/" type="hidden">

    {{ form.non_field_errors }}

    <div class="control-group input_id_username">
      {{ form.username.errors }}
      <label class="control-label" for="id_username">
        {{ form.username.label }}
      </label>
      <div class="controls">
          <input autofocus="" id="id_username" maxlength="30" name="username" required="" value="{{ form.username.value }}" type="text">
          <span class="help-inline">Only letters, numbers, dashes or underscores please.</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group input_id_website ">
      {{ form.website.errors }}
      <label class="control-label" for="id_website">
        {{ form.website.label }}
      </label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input id="id_website" maxlength="200" name="website" type="text" value="{{ form.website.value|default:'' }}" />
        <span class="help-inline"></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group input_id_bio">
      {{ form.bio.errors }}
      <label class="control-label" for="id_bio">
        {{ form.bio.label }}
      </label>
      <div class="controls">
        <textarea cols="40" id="id_bio" name="bio" rows="10">{{ form.bio.value|default:'' }}</textarea>
        <span class="help-inline"></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <input class="btn btn-primary btn-large" type="submit" value="{{ title }}"> or <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Cancel</a>
    </div>
  </form>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that there is an easy way to do what you are trying to do with Mezzanine (currently).  If you haven't already I would try posting in the Mezzanine Google group, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mezzanine-users.  You are likely to get more responses there

Comment: @joshcartme: Thanks. The [hack](https://github.com/hypertexthero/fn/blob/master/main/templates/accounts/account_form.html) described above seems to be working well so far.

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out!